# the results of murmurhash in pyspark and local python are different

Tags: pyspark, murmurhash

i use murmurhash to compute the hash value, but i got the results of murmurhash in pyspark and local python are different.

[image]

[image]

local python:
the hash value of 54958 is 5309672324031917724

pyspark:
the hash value of 54958 is -878367076

Comment: try using it with the `signed=False`  attribute

Comment: The value returned by Python is presumably a 64-bit unsigned integer (because the 64-bit version of MurmurHash3 is used). The result from psyspark looks like it could be a signed 32-bit integer. It cannot hold an unsigned 64-bit integer, and overflow occurs as a result. You would want to figure out how to make sure the hash is stored and displayed as an unsigned 64-bit integer.

Comment: @samkart i've tried this too, but it's not work

Comment: @njuffa thanks, change the udf value to long that it's ok, as IntegerType is 4 byte, LongType is 8 byte.